# How to determine when the value pointed to by a pointer is nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, pointers, cocos2d-iphone

I have a situation where troops can attack buildings. Each troop keeps a pointer to its target.

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) Building *target;
```

In an update loop, the troops periodically cause damage to their target.

```
if (_target)  
{
    if (/*enough time has passed since last attack, attack again*/)
    {
        [_target attack];
        if (_target.health <= 0)
        {
            [_target removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];   //Cocos2d
            _target = nil;
        }
    }
}
else /* Find new target */
```

---

The problem is:

- `troop1` deals the blow that fells `building1` and moves on to `building2`
- `troop2` was attacking `building1` but waits until its next attack to determine that `building1` is now `nil`.

I realise the problem is that `troop2`'s **pointer** has not been set to nil and instead I should be checking that the **value of the pointer** is nil.

I tried using `if (*_target)` but was met with the message

> Statement requires expression of scalar type

If there a way to achieve this kind of comparison in Objective-C? What other options are there for determining when a value has changed? KVO? Some extensive delegate pattern?

Comment: `_target` is already a pointer so `if (_target)` or `if (_target != nil)` is correct.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how `target1` and `target2` are defined? Are they both defined according to the pattern at the beginning of your question?

Comment: It's not 100% clear what you're asking, but pointers to Objective-C are essentially never dereferenced like that, and `weak` object pointers are indeed nil'd when the object in question is deallocated. In other words, the cause of the problem is not as you've described.

Comment: @bdesham, Yes, both are defined in the same way and would be assigned to that property.

Comment: @trojanfoe You should turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: @trojanfoe `if(_target)` isn't correct in that it doesn't work and returns a non-nil value when the object has been removed. As @Andrew points out though, the issue may be underlying.

Comment: I think relying on ARC to do this *zeroing* in unreliable and you probably need to abstract the target reference with some central dictionary.  I.e. Give each object a unique identifier, store the identifier in referencing objects and ask for the object whenever you want to "use" it.  This will give more reliable results and relying on ARC to go round zeroing pointers (which is counter-intuitive and non-portable).

Comment: @trojanfoe I've added a bit more information about the interaction with `_target`

Comment: Sorry for the variable naming confusion there. Some of those `targets` should have been `troops`

Comment: Since `target` is a weak reference, assuming that `[_target removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];` removes all strong references to the target, all of the weak properties pointing to it will automatically be set to `nil` and your existing code will work fine.  If they are not automatically set to `nil`, then there is still a strong reference to the target somewhere.  Find and fix that, and this will work fine.

Comment: @Inafziger, I've been looking for the underlying problem, I think this will be it.

Comment: @Inafziger. It was indeed another strong reference, an array holding on to the buildings, would you like to post an answer?

Comment: *Tut tut* It seems either TrojanFoe or Monolo has taken umbridge to me not thinking their answers were correct and removed their upvote and downvoted my question instead. Petty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the pointer itself that is set to nil when the object it points to is deallocated. `if (objectPointer == nil)` is always the way to check if an object is nil in Objective-C/Cocoa. If the pointer is not nil, it means the object in question has not in fact been deallocated. If you dereference a pointer to an object, you get a struct, hence the compiler error about needing a scalar value in the if expression.

So, in your case, if `if(self.target != nil)` is not giving you the result you expect, you should look for remaining strong references to the target (from other objects).

More broadly, as hinted at by trojanfoe's answer, you're relying on ARC's zeroing weak reference behavior for real program logic. In theory this is OK, as (contrary to his initial statement), ARC's zeroing weak behavior is reliable/deterministic. But, it does mean that you have to ensure that targets are *always* deallocated when they're no longer on the playing field (or whatever). This is a bit fragile. Zeroing weak references are intended as a way to avoid retain cycles (essentially a form of memory leak), rather than as a way to implement logic the way you're doing. The gist of trojanfoe's solution, where you explicitly register and unregister targets as necessary, is probably a more robust solution.

Answer (score 2):

There may be something that I have overlooked here, but to check if the `target2` property is `nil`, just do:

```
if ( self.target2 == nil ) {
     // Something
}
```

Comment: There is no `target2` property, the `target2` in my example is another instance of Troop. This is my fault, badly named!

Comment: That's what the `if (_target)` attempts to do, but it returns a non-nil value

Comment: The problem is `if (_target)` checks the pointer, I need to check the *value of the pointer*

Comment: Yeah, that was part of my question: `If there a way to achieve this kind of comparison in Objective-C?`

Comment: @JamesWebster It is the pointer itself that is set to nil when the object it points to is deallocated. `if (objectPointer == nil)` is *always* the way to check if an object is nil in Objective-C/Cocoa. If the pointer is not nil, it means the object in question has not in fact been deallocated. If you dereference a pointer to an object, you get a struct, hence the compiler error about needing a scalar value in the if expression.

Comment: @AndrewMadsen, could you post that as an answer please

Comment: Note that the code that James is using is equivalent to this.  I.e. `if (_target)` is the same as `if (_target == nil)`. However your code isn't necessarily the same if he over-rides the getter for target.

Comment: @JamesWebster, sure, I just posted an answer with a little bit added.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are relying too heavily on the implementation of ARC in that you only know if an object has been removed if the pointer is `nil`.  This is non-portable <strike>and can you make any guarantee between the object being released and the pointer becoming `nil`?</strike>

Instead, use a central dictionary of objects, mapped against their unique ID and store just this unique ID rather than the object pointer itself.  In this example I'm using a `NSNumber` for the key using an incrementing integer, but there are probably better keys that can be used.  Also `Object` is the base class of any object you want to store in this dictionary:

```
// Probably ivars in a singleton class
unsigned _uniqueId = 1;
NSMutableDictionary *_objects;

- (NSNumber *)addObject:(Object *)object
{
    NSNumber *key = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:_uniqueId++];
    [_objects setObject:object forKey:key];
    return key;
}

- (void)removeObjectForKey:(NSNumber *)key
{
    [_objects removeObjectForKey:key];
}

- (Object *)getObjectForKey:(NSNumber *)key
{
    return [_objects objectForKey:key];
}
```

And in your target, simply store the building key:

```
@property (strong) NSNumber *buildingKey;
```

and get the building via the methods provided:

```
Building *building = (Building *)[objectDictionary objectForKey:buildingKey];
if (building != nil)
{
    // building exists
}
else
{
    // building does not exist; throw away the key
    buildingKey = nil;
}
```

Comment: "This is non-portable and can you make any guarantee between the object being released and the pointer becoming nil?"  True, this is non-portable to another compiler that doesn't support ARC.  However, YES, you can guarantee that when an object is released that the pointer will become `nil` because that is what a weak reference in ARC does.  It is part of the definition of weak references.

Comment: I was reading this slowly before I disputed, but Inafziger has done it for me =]

Comment: Quite an overkill solution, I just added an `isDestroyed` Boolean property to Building =P

Answer (score 1):

Since target is a weak reference, your code should work "as-is", assuming that `[_target removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];` removes all strong references to the target.

When the last strong reference is removed, all of the weak properties pointing to it will automatically be set to `nil`. If they are not automatically set to `nil`, then there is still a strong reference to the target somewhere.

Find and remove that reference, and this will work fine.

Comment: Note also, that unless you have a specific reason to use the iVar directly, it is common to use the method (ie `self.target`) so that it is easier in the future if you suddenly find that you need to make changes to the logic that provides a target.